# drf_spectacular schema generation with custom parser

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I'm using a custom parser on my POST endpoint so that I can support file uploads and nested objects in the same endpoint ([context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896441/how-can-i-send-multipart-form-data-that-contains-json-object-and-image-file-via)):

```py
class MultipartJsonParser(parsers.MultiPartParser):
    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        result = super().parse(stream, media_type=media_type, parser_context=parser_context)
        return parsers.DataAndFiles(json.loads(result.data["data"]), result.files)
```

Data is posted as multipart/form-data with a single "data" key containing the full form as a json string, for example:

```
data: "{\"about\": {\"name\": \"a\"}}"
```

My serializer is defined like so:

```py
def AboutSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

def FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    about = AboutSerializer()
    # more fields
```

My drf_spectacular schema shows this endpoint expects an "about" field, but actually the POST request body should be a "data" field containing a JSON string with the "about" field inside of it.

Is there any way to make drf_spectqacular aware of my custom parser, so that the schema reflects that the only key in the form body should be data, and that data should be a JSON-encoded version of my FooSerializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized this can't be done in drf_spectacular. However, depending on which schema/api tools you use on the frontend, you may be able to convert to the desired format there. I'm using [openapi-fetch](https://openapi-ts.pages.dev/openapi-fetch/) for type-aware fetching in typescript, and was able to achieve this with the following [bodySerializer](https://openapi-ts.pages.dev/openapi-fetch/api/#bodyserializer):

```js
export function multipartJsonBodySerializer(body: Record<string, unknown>) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const jsonData: Record<string, unknown> = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(body)) {
    if (value instanceof File) {
      formData.append(key, value);
    } else {
      jsonData[key] = value;
    }
  }
  formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  return formData;
}

// Example post:
const body = {"about": {"name": "a"}}
POST("/api/endpoint/", {
      body: body,
      bodySerializer: multipartJsonBodySerializer,
})
```

The body object is type-checked as usual then it's converted to my custom format by the `bodySerializer`, before being posted.