# Is it possible to send custom (non-standard mime-type) files over a RESTful interface?

Tags: rest, file-upload, mime-types

I would like to be able to have one of my users click a file chooser

```
<input type="file"  multiple />
```

They would then be able to select one or more files that have a particular extension (chosen for use for this application, on a file designed for use with this application), and submit those files to a RESTful interface to be processed.

I've seen examples where a file is submitted as a part of a multi-part form.  Such as: [REST - HTTP Post Multipart with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081079/rest-http-post-multipart-with-json)

However, the header information for each part lists the format of the context, for example "image/jpeg".

If the file I have created for this custom application is not of a standard mime type, can I still somehow transmit multiple files?  What about if I want to also send some xml or json data in the same multi-part request?

Do the extension and mime-type always match?  For example, if I wanted to send over a serialized object from some language, or an xml file containing the info, but wanted to give it a customized extension, could I still use a corresponding mime type?