# can we use content type octet stream and json together?

Tags: java, json, rest, inputstream, contenttype

I have created a one rest service for uploading file.
My service consume Stream for file and Map of String for some info.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void upload(InputStream file,Map<String, String> fileInfoMap) {}
```

If yes then how to call service with POSTMAN?
if not then please suggest some alternatives?

Comment: check this if its helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081079/rest-http-post-multipart-with-json

Answer (score 0):

add  `multipart/mixed`  content_type in postman , under body section select form-data like below attached image[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi I have used application/octet-stream for file. It works for me. but how to get Map<String, String> fileInfoMap. should I need to add some annotation here?

Comment: try multipart/mixed or multipart/form-data

Comment: add  @Consumes("multipart/mixed")

Answer (score 0):

Try with postman if that doesn't work try curl

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" -F "fileInfoMap="name=xxx&age=24&location=yyy";type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -F "file=@somefile.zip" http://localhost:8080/upload
```