# How to handle post request with both query parameters and xml file

Tags: xml, rest, api, spring-boot, httprequest

I am developing web APIs using Spring Boot. I want one of the APIs to handle a POST request with an xml file and a few additional parameters. If it is just xml, I can just set the content-type to `application/xml`. And if it is just a couple parameters, I can do `param1=value1&param2=value2` with type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. However how do I deal with both types with one endpoint at the same time?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking for, but you could either put the parameters to the query part of the endpoint, or use multipart content-type, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081079/rest-http-post-multipart-with-json. It feels to me like the design change should be considered though.

Comment: @FrantišekŽiačik  How would you suggest I change the design? The params come from the device that is sending the request, e.g. mac address of phone. The file is generated from an mobile app. I don't think it is easy to combine both.

Comment: Depends on use case. In your case, it seems to me it should be sufficient to just use the xml content type and put the params in url. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deal with one end-point. Just specify the correct content type on your methods.

Since you tagged `sprint-boot`, I assume that you use Spring MVC? If yes, specify the proper `consumes` on the `RequestMapping`.

Comment: if I specify the content type as "application/xml" it would ignore the query params, right?

Comment: No. Request can have query parameters on url despite the content type. If you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it basically means that you have query parameters in the body AND you can also have them on url.