# Upload files along with data using REST API

Tags: php, json, rest, file-handling

I have created an `API in PHP` to save the form data in the database. The API will be used for both Web and Mobile APP. The API is receiving data in `JSON` an sends the response in `JSON` only. I am using `PHP CURL` to call the API, no `AJAX` call will be there.

> API (employee-registration.php)

```
<?php
    $params = file_get_contents('php://input');     // Input stream

    // Set initial values
    $salutation = $first_name = $last_name = $email = "";

    // Extract data
    $json = json_decode($params);

    $salutation         = trim($json->salutation);
    $first_name         = trim($json->first_name);
    $last_name          = trim($json->last_name);
    $email              = trim($json->email);

    // Do the validation and save data in database
    // Then send response in JSON

    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->status = $status;
    $obj->message = $message;
    $obj->errors = $errors;
    echo json_encode($obj);
?>
```

> Call API using CURL

```
<?php
    $site_path = "http://www.mywebsite.com/";

    $postData = array(
        'salutation'    => 'mr',
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Pinto',
        'email' => 'test@website.com'
    );
    $postData = json_encode($postData);
    $ch = curl_init();  
    $url = $site_path.'path/to/api/employee-registration.php';
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;
?>
```

The above things are working perfect, I am sending JSON data to the API and receiving JSON data from the API. But what if there is a file with all other data, say `profile_picture`. How can I modify the API so that it can receive data in JSON from Web and Mobile APP with the file? Ajax call is not allowed here, I have to use CURL for Web. please help

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but here's how you send the data ~ https://stackoverflow.com/q/9081079/283366. As for how to receive / decode the request, you may just need to experiment. I'm not entirely sure what data will be in the `php://input` stream for a `multipart/form-data` request

Comment: Thank you for your comment but that did not solve my problem